# ActiveRecord not finding existing records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I try to create a new 'Refill' record, but I'm getting this error message:

```
Couldn't find Vehicle with ID=1 for Refill with ID=
```

But if I do a direct select in the SQLite3 database the vehicle record is there.

Here is the relevant code:

vehicle class:

```
class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :refills, :inverse_of=> :vehicle
    validates_presence_of :prefix, :plate, :diesel_type
end
```

refill class:

```
class Refill < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :vehicle
    validates_presence_of :date, :mileage, :liters, :vehicle
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :vehicle
end
```

refill_params method:

```
def refill_params
  params.require(:refill).permit(:date, :mileage, :liters, vehicle_attributes: [:id])
end
```

the json I'm trying to POST:

```
{
    "refill": {
        "date": "2017-01-01",
        "mileage": 125000,
        "liters": 115,
        "vehicle_attributes": {
            "id": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the JSON have to look like that?  It's more usual to have `params.require(:refill).permit(:date, :mileage, :liters, :vehicle_id)` and to just pass `"vehicle_id": 1` in the JSON. You don't really need `accepts_nested_attributes...`

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. :)